# Ghostscript to convert graphics to rich black when converting to CMYK

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, graphic, cmyk

**I'm using Ghostscript 9.22 to convert a PDF to CMYK, but can't seem the get the right CMYK-values for a black colored graphic object:**

- input PDF (rgb): contains 2 images and 1 (black, `R: 0%, G: 0%, B: 0%`) graphic.
- output PDF (cmyk): images are converted correctly, but the black color of the graphic is: `C: 100%, M: 100%, Y: 100%, K: 0%`:

[image]

**I need to have the black of the graphic set to specific values:**

```
C: 0%, M: 0%, Y: 0%, K: 100%
```

or

```
C: 75%, M: 68%, Y: 67%, K: 90% (rich black)
```

**Any idea how I can realise this?**

This is the Ghostscript command used:

`gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output-cmyk.pdf -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dAutoFilterMonoImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dMonoImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dDownsampleGrayImages=false -dDownsampleColorImages=false -dDownsampleMonoImages=false input-rgb.pdf`